# Swift_Mailer thrown Connection Timeout error on server

Tags: php, symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

My setup for submitting an e-mail is:

```
$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport(
    'smtp.gmail.com',
    465,
    'ssl'
))
    ->setUsername(*username*)
    ->setPassword(*password*)
    ->setTimeout(12);

$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
```

Testing this configuration in XAMPP works very well, but when I try to use the same configuration on a server I receive: `Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)`.

On the server `ConfigServer Security & Firewall` have:

- SMTP_BLOCK = Off

What configuration is missing, to `Swift_Mailer` sending emails without error?

Comment: Google disabled access for third party applications last year. Your application is a third party application. Have you tried a different SMTP server? If you don't have one, register on MailGun or something.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cif-less-secure-app-access-is-on-for-your-account

Comment: I used third party app password to login and not email password

Comment: Ok, with an app password you can use the SMTP server. I did not know that. I thought Google had closed completely.

Are you testing from a corporate network or is this happening on a business hosting environment? There, outgoing ports are restricted and have to be opened first.

Have you tested it with another service like MailGun?

I would first try to exclude things that could have to do with the Google network.

Comment: In local machine it work and in business hosting environment don't.
Teste with outlook, same problem, but with email from another hosting environment work.
Have used ports in TCP_IN and TCP_OUT.
Turned off SMTP_BLOCK.

Comment: Good, it works on your local computer. So it's not a wrong configuration of SwiftMail.

You should contact the hoster or the administrator of the servers. With business hosters, all outgoing ports are usually deactivated on the firewall (on the server or in the network) or the ports are open and you have to explicitly allow which host you want to connect to.

I can't help you there now. The error message also sounds like the connection is blocked. You have to clarify this with the hoster or the administrator of the server.